# POST request not working with JSON input using Restlet

Tags: java, json, rest, post, restlet

I'm using Restlet framework to implement a POST request for a REST resource, which is supposed to accept JSON formatted data. Problem is, I keep getting the `415 Unsupported Media Type` error.

The odd thing is that I've set a breakpoint right inside the function responsible for handling the POST request, and when the input is of `application/json`, debug does NOT stop at the breakpoint (meaning the function handling POST requests is not even called, and the error just comes beforehand). However if I change the input to `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, debug DOES stop at the breakpoint. So why isn't the POST function called when input is of `application/json` type ?

**Here is the request:**

```
POST /res2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 121a2782-0b4e-f592-8d78-26f07862d5fd

{"id":3,"name":"John Smith","age":23,"gender":"Male"}
```

**The output HTML message states:**

```
The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

**Main Application code:**

```
package com.poc.hw11;

import xyz (trimming to save space)

public class JSON_POC extends Application
{
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot()
    {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/res1", Resource1.class);
    return router;
    }
}
```

**Resource1 Class:**

```
package com.poc.hw11;

import xyz (trimming to save space);

public class Resource1 extends ServerResource
{
    @Post
    public void addPerson() {

        Request request = getRequest(); // BREAKPOINT SET ON THIS LINE. DEBUG DOESN'T REACH THIS POINT WHEN INPUT IS OF application/json TYPE
        Response response = getResponse();

        //Rest of code here.
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing `@Post` to `@Post("json")`, but the result is the same .. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

if you want manually handle the incoming representation, I would you the following syntax:

```
@Post
public void addPerson(Representation rep) {
  System.out.println(rep.getMediaType());
  Request request = getRequest();
  Response response = getResponse();

}
```

But I would let automatic converter handle this:
Create a bean Contact having the structure of your json, then let the jackson converter deal with deserialization :

```
@Post
public void addPerson(Contact contact) {
  System.out.println(contact.getName());
}
```

In order to add the Jackson converter, just complete the classpath of your application with the Jackson extension for Restlet Framework (org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar) and its dependencies (the jackson libraries com.fasterxml.*.jar shipped with Restlet)

Please fell free to ask for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The default content type for post requests is url-encoded form. If you need to handle some other type, you need to find the way to specify that in your code. For example,  if I were using Jersey,  I would use the @Consumes annotation to specify the expected content type for this post request. You need to find out how to do the same in restlet framework.

Comment: Regrettably this answers a different question.